# how to start a project in ddev with a bigger disk size

Tags: ddev

I installed ddev on my macbook. I initiated a drupal7 project and wanted to proceed with the db import. However, this import could not complete due to lack of disk size.

What would be the best way to increase the available disk size?
I do have more than 100GB available on my laptop, but the database container doesn't seem to take not of that available space.

SSH-ing into the project (ddev ssh), I noticed that the partition for mysql was full...

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just change the size of the disk allocation for Docker.

On Docker Desktop (macOS and Win10 Pro) this is under the "advanced" section of the preferences or settings menu. This is non-destructive.

On Docker Toolbox (Win 10 Home typically), you set up the docker-machine with the size you want, as [shown in the docs](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/docker_installation/#windows-installation-docker-toolbox) - I don't think there's a way to increase the disk size on Docker Toolbox without it being essentially a factory reset.

Answer (score 2):

it's apparantly as easy as going to the preferences screen of your Docker Desktop and increase the disk size of the vm there...